# clear value in an input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a number of inputs for telephone numbers, they use the same class and the same show/hide techinque. 
I want to be able to clear the contents of the phone number in the input box, i.e. with the class name of input_tel.

However it seems to clear all inputs which I assume is because I am using the following line; `input:text` , when I put in a class it just fails to work.

My JS and some of my html is below or view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/DdPmR/):

```
$(".contact_numbers").on('click', '.clearnumber', function () {
  $(this).siblings('input:text').val('');
});

<div class="telephonetwo contact_numbers">
   <input type="text" class="smallinput contactpagelabel" name="faxname" size="10" value="Fax">
   <input type="checkbox" class="contact_no" name="showfax" value="Y">      
   <input type="text" name="fax" size="30" value="016128 13456" class="input_tel">
   <a href="#" class="remove">Hide</a> <a href="#" class="clearnumber">Clear #</a>
 </div>
```

#### If you are viewing my JSfiddle click the reveal additional numbers for the clear button to appear.

#### Update

I want to be able to clear the closest input_tel rather than all of them, as their are multiple numbers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace:

```
$(this).siblings('input:text').val('');
```

with

```
$(this).siblings('input:text').closest('.input_tel').val('');
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DdPmR/8/)

Comment: that clears the whole line I want it to clear the closest input_tel class

Comment: not to worry changed your type to class and replaced the name

Answer (score 2):

How about targeting the `input_tel` class then?

```
$(".contact_numbers").on('click', '.clearnumber', function () {
   $(this).parent().parent().find('input.input_tel').val('');
});
```

Assuming no other input fields have that `input_tel` class on them.

Comment: What if you step up two levels with `parent()` and then target the class, like my new edit?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
$(".contact_numbers").on('click', function () {
  $(".input_tel").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**The safe way to clear input fields with jquery**

```
$.fn.noText = function() {/*use the jquery prototype technology to make a chainable clear field method*/
    if(this.is('input')){ /*check to c if you the element type is an input*/
        this.val('');/*clear the input field*/
    }return this;/*means it is chainable*/
};
$('input').noText();
```